# How to deploy an App Service Extension via Terraform or ARM?

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-rm-template

We are using an **extension** for our AppService. How do I automate adding it via ARM template and/or Terraform? I cannot find it in Azure generated ARM template for the app or service plan.

Thanks!

[image: app service extension screenshot]

Comment: So, my understanding is that Extensions are just NuGets, so if you add the NuGet you need to your project (while in development, in Visual Studio), this NuGet will be included during deployment. ARMs are for environment set-up, this is already a code dependency. I guess they made this available in case you are writing something directly in azure for a quick test, but probably you should not rely on this.

Comment: This extension we are using to make sure that our dot net core code runs in 64 bit environment. Just switching it in Azure portal App settings (toggle switch) to 64 bits did not make it run in 64 bits until we added this extension. The project targets "Any CPU" so I think it is up to the host if it runs it in x86 or x64. Somehow by adding this extension I forced it to run in x64. I can see that the host App Service has both x86 and x64 dotnet.exe installed, but I could not make it work in x64 without the extension.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a template you could refer to, use parameters extensionName `AspNetCoreRuntime.2.2.x64` and extensionVersion `2.2.0-preview3-35497` as your desired. You could find the extension info in [Azure Resource Explorer](https://resources.azure.com/).

```
{
   "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
   "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
   "parameters": {
       "siteName": {
           "type": "string",
           "metadata": {
               "description": "The Azure App Service Name"
           }
       },
       "extensionName": {
           "type": "string",
           "metadata": {
               "description": "The Site Extension Name."
           }
       },
       "extensionVersion": {
           "type": "string",
           "metadata": {
               "description": "The Extension Version"
           }
       }
   },
   "resources": [
       {
           "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/siteextensions",
           "name": "[concat(parameters('siteName'), '/', parameters('extensionName'))]",
           "apiVersion": "2015-04-01",
           "location": "[resourceGroup().location]",
           "properties": {
               "version": "[parameters('extensionVersion')]"
           }
       }
   ]
}
```

Result:

[image]

You also could use the ARM Template in Terraform. You could add an [azurerm_deployment_template](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azurerm/r/template_deployment.html) block in `main.tf`. It's like this

```
resource "azurerm_template_deployment" "extension" {
  name                = "extension"
  resource_group_name = "${azurerm_resource_group.main.name}"
  template_body       = "${file("arm/siteextensions.json")}"

  parameters {
    "siteName"          = "${azurerm_app_service.main.name}"
    "extensionName"     = "AspNetCoreRuntime.2.2.x64"
    "extensionVersion"  = "2.2.0-preview3-35497"
  }

  deployment_mode     = "Incremental"
}
```

You could get more details from this blog regarding [applying Azure App Service extensions with ARM](https://www.phillipsj.net/posts/applying-azure-app-service-extensions-with-arm)

Comment: thanks! I went through the blog once before and could not find the value in the resource explorer. If I add the extension from the portal manually, I still cannot find the ARM part in the resource explorer. 

However if I initially add it with the Terraform/ARM template, then I can find it under `subscriptions > [mySubscription] > resourceGroups > [myResourceGroup] > providers > Microsoft.Resources > deployments > extension > operations`. Anyway, I managed to do it in the end with Terraform and ARM template.

Answer (score 2):

The [`azurerm_template_deployment`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/template_deployment) is superseded by [`azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment`](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/resource_group_template_deployment) and will be deprecated.

Here's the example configuration I used to enable Datadog extension in Azure App Service for reference:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group_template_deployment" "dd_extension" {
  name                = "dd-extension"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  deployment_mode     = "Incremental"

  parameters_content = jsonencode({
    "site_name" = {
      value = var.web_app_name
    }
  })

  template_content = "${file("arm/siteextensions.json")}"
}
```

```json
{
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/schemas/2015-01-01/deploymentTemplate.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "parameters": {
        "site_name": {
            "type": "string"
        }
    },
    "resources": [
        {
            "type": "Microsoft.Web/sites/siteextensions",
            "apiVersion": "2021-01-15",
            "name": "[concat(parameters('site_name'), '/Datadog.AzureAppServices.DotNet')]",
            "location": "[resourceGroup().location]"
        }
    ]
}
```